# Can I make a search query which includes a space?

Tags: wp-query, search

I want to search via `WP_Query` for the test "hello " including the last trailing space.

Is this possible and if so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible at all, this is how it would be done:

```
$searchquery = new WP_Query( array(
    's' => 'hello '
));
```

Since all queries boil down to `WP_Query` at their most basic level, we can determine if it is possible using the WordPress APIs by looking at the code in `wp-includes/query.php`

```
// If a search pattern is specified, load the posts that match
if ( !empty($q['s']) ) {
    // added slashes screw with quote grouping when done early, so done later
    $q['s'] = stripslashes($q['s']);
    if ( !empty($q['sentence']) ) {
        $q['search_terms'] = array($q['s']);
    } else {
        preg_match_all('/".*?("|$)|((?<=[\r\n\t ",+])|^)[^\r\n\t ",+]+/', $q['s'], $matches);
        $q['search_terms'] = array_map('_search_terms_tidy', $matches[0]);
    }
    $n = !empty($q['exact']) ? '' : '%';
    $searchand = '';
    foreach( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}(($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}'))";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }

    if ( !empty($search) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
}

// Allow plugins to contextually add/remove/modify the search section of the database query
$search = apply_filters_ref_array('posts_search', array( $search, &$this ) );
```

From this we can determine that at multiple stages the search string is stripped and cleaned, and any additional spaces would be removed as part of the sanitisation process.

The only way to conduct such a search would be to reproduce that process using the `posts_search` filter to reproduce the SQL using your own sanitation process, but I **strong** recommend against this, for security and maintenance reasons. I would advise whatever system you have, it would be easier to re-architect it than to go down this route, and it could be argued that to do so would be irresponsible as a developer, and non trivial.

Instead I suggest you do your search using a dedicated SQL tool such as workbench, and a query similar to the below:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE "hello " LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Are you sure? I think the space is ignored.

Comment: if it is ignored then the answer is no, it isn't possible. You'll need to implement your own search function with a raw SQL query. Can I ask why you'd want such a feature?

Comment: I have a legal portal. Posts are laws. One custom field holds the legal references.  These are like " law 11 law 17 law 135".

Comment: I allow my users to search legal references custom field for e.g. "law 15" and my code enters leading and trailing spaces so as not to bring "law 151" as well. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The legal references may be any large number so it is impossible to enter them in distinct custom fields, so I opted on insering them in a single field.

Comment: hmmm the code above in my answer demonstrates that post meta are not searched anyway

Comment: My thinking is that you'll need to implement a custom setup. I would have used a taxonomy and terms, that way you only need autocomplete for the legal reference in a dedicated searchbox and have super fast easy listings

Comment: Also keep in mind that the example provided would not catch instances such as law 15. law 15, law 15! law 15s or the case of law 15 at the end of a line, post or closing tag ( so it wouldn't catch bolded law 15 ).

Comment: Thanks. The legal references are entered by legal staff so they will be in the form of space-law-space-law. But from your answer I get that my solution is unworkable and I should opt for taxonomy, correct?

Comment: With a taxonomy it would be easier to enter them in the backend, and you wouldn't need to do a full text search. It also dramatically simplifies things like related posts

Comment: Please can you recommend a starting pointer RE taxonomies. I assume I can assign one article to many taxonomies, correct?
Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, and a term can have many articles assigned to it, just look up custom taxonomies and it's all rather self explanatory, themergency have a tax registration code generator too, look here for how to autocomplete: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41348/autocomplete-for-taxonomy-input-boxes-on-a-front-end-form